# Mysql query help to get users count from table area wise

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table which is having some report info. In that table I have `userid` and `areaname` .

Now my requirement is to get the count of user's list based on area

For example table will have

```
userid | areaname
-----------------
1       |area 1
1      |area 1
2      |area2
2      |area 2
2      |area2
3      |area1
3      |area1
4      |area3
5      |area2
---------------
```

Result must be

```
area1 2users
area2 2users
area3 1user
```

what is the mysql query to achieve this?

Comment: You have no primary key - which may prove problematic in due course

Comment: hi i have primary key in my real table for asking question simpler and easier way to project i created this exmple. i hope you understand

Comment: I think it's always sensible to include the PRIMARY KEY in your question - whether you think you need it or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Aggregate function `COUNT()` to get the number of users and `GROUP BY` to get the count based on `areaname`
Use `DISTINCT` for unique values

```
 SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT userid),areaname FROM tablename GROUP BY areaname;
```

Comment: this will also add dupe entries note my table have dupe entries for users

Comment: @Sabeena Check my edit..Use DISTINCT in the query to avaoid dupe entries

Answer (score 0):

I see, you can have dublicate entries ad well:

So I would make a sub Select

```
SELECT sum(partly_sum), area 
       FROM (
           SELECT 
               userid, area , count(*) as partly_sum 
                  FROM 
                      _YOUR_TABLE_NAME_ 
                  WHERE 1 
                  GROUP BY area, userid
             ) as a_bad_sub_query 
       WHERE 1 
       GROUP BY area
```

Regards

Comment: this will also add dupe entries note my table have dupe entries for users

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT count(userid),area FROM YOURTABLENAME GROUP BY area;
```

Comment: this will also add dupe entries note my table have dupe entries for users

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow :-)
Please look at [answer]. You should provide some information why your code solves the problem.
Code-only answers aren't useful for the community.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `distinct` to avoid dupe entries

`SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT userid),areaname FROM tablename GROUP BY areaname`